# How configure Identity Server v3 for login only once persist for 30 days?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application, identityserver3

I want to create the application where is the requirement for login process that the user have to login only once per 30 days.

The application scenario is the single page application will be written in the angularjs with the access to the web api.

How can I configure the Identity server v3 for login only once?

What is the recommended life time of access token for this scenario if I want to persist the login for 30 days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure IdentityServer to issue 30 day persistent cookies. https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/authenticationOptions.html

Also, you can control if IdentityServer accepts the incoming cookie from the user via `IAuthenticationSessionValidator`. The basic approach would be to look at at the time the user logged in and not allow the cookie if it's older than 30 days. https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/session-invalidation.html

Comment: I've found the choice to use the reference token: https://leastprivilege.com/2015/11/25/reference-tokens-and-introspection/ - I'm wondering about get ask identity server for this type of token (reference token) and store this acess token into cookie where I set HTTPONLY and SECURE flags. Every request reads via owin module this cookie and set value of access token as the authorization attribute and send to the api, what do you think about it? Thanks for your points.

Comment: Leaving long-lived access tokens around is an enormous security pitfall, even if they are reference token. Access tokens cannot be revoked, and you are using them inside a JavaScript application which is insecure by nature. Using Brock Allen approach is your best option: keep the user logged in inside IdentityServer and keep renewing access tokens with short TTL.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma You can revoke the reference token.